# eigenfaces with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, pca

I just recognized some faces with `cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer`.
But what I want is to know how much the input face looks like the calculated eigenfaces.
The idea is that you can rerecognize persons that are not in the database.

EDIT:

for example: I have face A, B and C trained on my model, then I see face C and D. I want to be able to differentiate face C from D.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a section on setting thresholds in the documentation on `cv::FaceRecognizer` at:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#setting-the-thresholds

It works just the same for the OpenCV Python Wrapper, which you can easily see when calling `help(cv2.createFaceRecognizer)` in Python:

```
Help on built-in function createEigenFaceRecognizer in module cv2:

createEigenFaceRecognizer(...)
    createEigenFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval
```

So in the code you would create the model with a threshold, I'll set it to `100.0`. Anything below this will yield `-1` in the prediction, which means this face is `unknown`:

```
# Create the Eigenfaces model. We are going to use the default
# parameters for this simple example, please read the documentation
# for thresholding:
model = cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer(threshold=100.0)
```

As shown in the demo, you can get the prediction and associated confidence (which is the distance to the nearest neighbor in the your training dataset) with:

```
[predicted_label, predicted_confidence] = model.predict(image)
```

So if you train your model on the subjects `A`, `B`, `C` **AND** you are using a threshold, then a prediction for `D` should yield `-1`, while `A`, `B` or `C` should be recognized. Given the fact, that you are using a threshold.

As for adding new faces iteratively without re-estimating the whole model. This is not possible for the Eigenfaces or Fisherfaces method. You always have to call `FaceRecognizer::train` for these two algorithms to learn the model. The Local Binary Patterns Histograms (LBPH) model, which you can create with `cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer`, supports updating a model without recalculating the other training samples. See the API Documentation on this:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#facerecognizer-update

Comment: sorry, with "rerecognize persons that are not in the database" I meant that you are able to rerecognize an unknown face again after seeing it without retraining the model.

Comment: To the people starting with opencv, `help(cv2.createFaceRecognizer)` will result in an error because there is no module `createFaceRecognizer`, took me a while before I gave up searching the source.

Comment: This is not correct. You can find a full source code example on how to use the OpenCV Python Bindings and Eigenface Model at: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/facerec_demo.py. There is no method such as ``cv2.createFaceRecognizer``, this is the reason you get an error. Have a look into the API documentation linked in the above answer, to see which functions are available.